# Why we should use transform to position a pop-up in the middle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I've wrote this code and the pop-up wasn't in its right position, so I added **transform** and it works. I wanna know the reason behind it.

```
.popup {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: using "left: 50%",  the element's left edge will be positioned at the horizontal midpoint of its containing element. So you need to center the element by moving itself to the left by "50%" of its own width (in this case popup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the anchor of the element is placed in the top left corner, not in the center of the element.

[image]